# XML compression compatible to both Java and C#

Tags: c#, java

Am building a C# front end that communicates to a Java Tomcat server via HTTP.

The WOX package is used to de/serialize the objects on the Java and C# ends.

However, I want to reduce the time spent in sending XML strings over HTTP, by using some XML compression packages.

My questions are:

1. Is using WOX de/serialization resulting in XML strings being passed back and forth, the best way to communicate between C# and Java?
2. What XML compression libraries (has to be free) should I consider to increase the speed?

Many thanks.
Chapax

Answer (score 2):

I'd initially try just applied gzip compression at the HTTP level - partly because that should be able to be applied transparently to your app. XML generally compresses pretty well. Do you have a specific target in mind, so you'll know when a result is "good enough"? (If not, that might be the first thing to work out - otherwise you won't know when to stop.) Tomcat supports gzip compression as a [connector configuration option](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html).

As for whether XML is the right way to go - it certainly has advantages and disadvantages. There are plenty of other serialization options, including [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) and [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). Each has pros and cons in terms of platform integration, size, readability, versioning etc. You should work out what's important to you and then look at the options in terms of those considerations.

Comment: Many thanks Jon ... what respective packages should I be using to apply gzip compression in Java/C#?

The "good enough" is really the ability to pass 200k rows of data ... in the shortest possible time.

Will consider the other XML serializers at a later point ... for now will work with WOX.

Thanks once again.

Comment: @Chapax: Gzip compression in Tomcat: see the linked connector configuration page. In C#, you may need to add a header ("Accept-Encoding: gzip") when you fetch, but that should be all you have to do.